# MC34262 PFC not reaching desired output voltage

Tags: power-factor-correction

I'm building a 450W PFC with a MC34262. It's the first time I build a PFC. I based my circuit on the reference design of page 12 of the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34262-D.PDF).

I'm testing with two 100W incandescent lamps in series (the output voltage of the PFC should be 400V). The problem is I'm only getting a 300V output voltage instead of 400V. Here is my schematic:

[image]

The inductor is made using two 33x19x11mm stacked yellow/white toroids (bought them [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008SOQLCG)). The primary has a 1 mH inductance and the secondary has 12 turns which gives me about 30V to power the MC34262.

This is the MOSFET gate waveform while powering the PFC with 220V RMS and the two 100W incandescent lamps in series as load:

[image]

Zoomed out waveform:

[image]

This is the waveform in the drain:

[image]

In both cases, with gate and drain waveforms I have to stop the scope in order to get a clear waveform, I can't trigger the signal properly (I can take a picture if needed). I don't know if that means the output from the MC34262 is not stable and therefore I'm not getting the full output power.

Just in case here is the line AC rectifier output:

[image]

As you can see the Vpk seems to be the same as the PFC output voltage.

And this is the pin 8 (Vcc) from the MC34262:

[image]

I found that the voltage on the compensation pin 2 is nearly 0V and according to the datasheet the voltage should be at least 1.33V, could that be the cause of the output not reaching 400V and not delivering the full output power?

Comment: Looks to me like you are hitting the over voltage protection at Vref*1.08 -> Vfb =~ 2.7V.  I don't think you can run it that high of an output voltage in this configuration.

Comment: ahh nevermind, I misread your first feedback resistor at 1 Meg, not 1.6 Meg

Comment: Refer to the block diagram. If pin 2 is nearly 0V, that implies pin 1 is higher than the Vfb threshold of 2.5V. But the actual condition should be 300V*10K/(1610K) = 1.9V. So that would be one of the first things to investigate.

Comment: @rioraxe The voltage on pin 1 is far from 2.5V, it's about 1.8V right now.

Comment: Refering to the block diagram of Figure 20. The Quickstart block is supposed to charge C1 at pin 2 with increased current when below 1.7V. The Error Amp is also supposed to charge C1 when pin 1 is below Vfb. I see no good explanation as to why pin 2 is stuck near ground except the IC being bad or for some unexpected wiring mistake.

Comment: When pin 2 is low, it causes the '-' reference of the Current Sense Comparator to be low, setting a low inductor current threshold. On your third waveform, the switch on time is around 400ns. You can derive the peak inductor current: dI = dt * V / L = 400ns * 300V / 1mH = 0.12A which is much lower than required.

Comment: Not sure if you ever figured this out, but I think it could be the feedback pin sinking current through your large valued step-down resistor, which is artificially making the chip think you are overvoltage. Why it doesn't use a high impedance input I don't know but the current requirement for the sensing pin and the possibility of this error in output voltage is mentioned in the datasheet. May or may not be your problem, but something to consider...

Comment: @Andres have your completed this design?